# Securely accessing a private API from my own consumer website using AJAX

Tags: ajax, api, security, backend, frontend

Could use some suggestions for how best to secure an API that for the time being will remain private.  The backend API has been developed and will lie on its own system.  The front end consumer website will have access to this API via a private API key.  This is all in server side code.  However, a new requirement has been made known: our website will also need to make AJAX requests to generate the code.  I don't want to expose the API calls or token in the javascript code, so I'm trying to figure out options.  One would be to create a REST controller on the front-end server-side which could then be called by javascript code, but this would effectively circumvent the API key security measure and therefore is not a true solution.

So what are the general practices for this?  I think ideally (and I'm moving toward this, it's just not feasible time-wise currently) I would use OAuth tokens to validate requests and have some API calls(pulling in general information) not require any form of authentication etc, but even that would have some issues given the AJAX requirements.  Is there perhaps some way to have client-side javascript and associated AJAX calls which will remain secure?

All this is to say - I'm currently at a loss of what to do here.

Thanks.

Edit:  Current thought is to create controllers on the front end which can be accessed via ajax, which sends non-risky fetches to the API, and for risky ones relies on current user validation (e.g. user being logged in).  Furthermore, logging in will not be an AJAX style request, so logging in should be a reliable security test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could develop a handler to accept the AJAX requests and pass them along to the private API using the normal access-token approach you would take elsewhere in non-public facing code.

That way, you don't expose the token or the API in javascript.  You can build a whitelist of API calls in your handler so that it only deals with (presumably) benign AJAX requests from the front-end. This handler is both a firewall for bad requests and a way to protect the real mechanics of the private API.

If any of the API methods are potentially dangerous or destructive to data, this can (and should) be used in conjunction with the public website's authentication mechanisms.

A mockup (in PHP):

```
$whitelist = array(
  'SomeApiCallPublicAlias'=>'RealApiMethod',
  'AnotherPublicAlias'=>'SomeSafeApiMethod'
);
$call = $_POST['call']; // <-- SomeApiCallPublicAlias
if (!array_key_exists($call, $whitelist))
  die('permission denied');
$data= $_POST['data'];

// hook in to the private API, pass the data, return the response
$response = make_private_api_call($whitelist[$call], $data);
die(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: I believe this is the "extra controller on the front-end server side" approach I mentioned above.  In other words, I could just create controllers which will pass calls to the server for all the calls which are safe to make.  The problem with this is there are going to be some "potentially dangerous calls" which will need to be made via AJAX, so merely whitelisting/accommodating certain calls isn't really ideal.

Comment: Yes, this is a take on one of the approaches you mentioned in the OP. You would combine this approach with whatever authentication you're using on the front-end--presumably, you would only be firing off "dangerous" requests in response to some user interaction, and presumably you would authenticate that user first. Your "extra controller" would implement your front-end authentication mechanism. Given the technology in use here, web, that is all sort of a foregone conclusion; I don't think there is "another way". You'll wind up with some iteration of this approach, I'm sure.

Comment: Hey Chris - your first response got my mind going and I just edited the question without seeing your reply here.  Appreciate the input, I'm going to accept your answer as it is the method I'll be implementing currently.  Thanks for helping me think through this.